# Print numbers diagonally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started python for 3 weeks and I am studying list and strings.
The required program is supposed to print this diagonal pattern where the pattern ends at the number the user enters. For example, the user enter number 4, it will print this pattern.

```
1
  2
    3
      4
```

However, the problem is when I enter integer 10, it will print:

```
1
  2
    3
      4
        5
          6
            7
              8
                9
                  1
                    0
```

I would like to know how to fix this problem as well as improve it.

Here is the code:

```
n = eval(input('Enter a number:'))
L =[]
for i in range(0,n):
    L.append(i+1)
N = ''.join([str(num) for num in L])
for index, number in enumerate(N):
    print(' '*index + number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your code as

```
n = int(input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range(n):
    print(' '*i + str(i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

as simple as it is:

```
n = int(input('Enter a number:'))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(' '*i, i)
```

Comment: But this will print numbers starting from 0 not 1.